# R | NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call | e1071 SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Chess+%28King-Rook+vs.+King-Pawn%29

Code:

```
require("e1071")

# Load the data into bank
bank <- read.csv("~/R/SVM/kr-vs-kp.data")
colnames(bank)[ncol(bank)] <- 'to.classify'
bank$to.classify <- as.factor(bank$to.classify)

# Divide the data into TRAIN and TEST sets
index <- 1:nrow(bank)
testIndex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testSet <- bank[testIndex,]
trainSet <- bank[-testIndex,]

# Learning sigmoid tuned nu-classification model
svm.nu.tune.model.sigmoid <- best.svm(to.classify ~ ., data = trainSet, coef0 = c(0,1,10,20,30), gamma = c(0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30), cost = c(1,3,10,30,100), nu = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9), na.action = na.omit, kernel = 'sigmoid',  type = 'nu-classification')
print(svm.nu.tune.model.sigmoid)
```

Error:

```
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 8)
```

The algorithm works fine on any other combination of kernel and type. This is the only problematic one.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.

It seems that for the given dataset some values for *nu* and *coef0* are infeasible and instead of skipping them it decides to throw away the whole work and crash instead.

*coef0* - apparently the values are from interval `0 <= coef0 <= 1`. Although this information is nowhere to be found. For anything larger than 1 it just crashes with NaN/Inf error.

*nu* - for anything larger than 0.7 for kr-vs-kp dataset it results into 'nu infeasible' error. For different smaller dataset different values (`0 < x < 0.4`) are infeasible.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you mix the parameters in the same call. If you just use the nu parameter with the nu-classification (and cost parameter with C-classification in another call) then it should work.

For example:

```
svm.nu.tune.model.sigmoid <- best.svm(to.classify ~ ., data = trainSet, nu = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9), na.action = na.omit, kernel = 'sigmoid',  type = 'nu-classification')
```

Comment: The other nu-classificators didn't have any problem with including cost parameter, although I admit I have forgotten to delete it. I removed it and reran the code but the problem persists.

`svm.nu.tune.model.sigmoid <- best.svm(to.classify ~ ., data = trainSet, coef0 = c(0,1,10,20,30), gamma = c(0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30), nu = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9), na.action = na.omit, kernel = 'sigmoid',  type = 'nu-classification')`